# Does a parent have its children's physicsBodies?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3, skphysicsbody

I was wondering what the physicsBody of a parent would be if all I do is this:

```
let combinedBodies = SKSpriteNode()
addChild(combinedBodies)

//Create its children like this as an example:
let child = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 10, height: 20))
child.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: child.size)
child.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = collisionType.child.rawValue
combinedBodies.addChild(child)
allBodies.append(child.physicsBody?)
```

Would the physicsBody of combinedBodies be the combination of all its children's physicsBodies, or would it have none and I would have to manually add it? Also, what would the `categoryBitMask` of the parent be? Would it be `collisionType.child.rawValue` if all of its children had that category, or would I manually have to give it its own category?

**Edit:** I have used this:

```
combinedBodies.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: )
```

I have a list where I store all the children's physicsBodies and then put that list into this command (I keep updating the `combinedBodies.physicsBody` when new and old children get deleted). **However,** now I have the problem that the physicsbodies of the parent aren't where the original physicsbodies of the children were (they are at different positions on the screen), they are in the middle of the screen. Is there a way to fix this?

I have also changed the physicsBody of the combinedBodies like this:

```
combinedBodies.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: allBodies)
combinedBodies.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
combinedBodies.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = collisionType.combinedBodies.rawValue
combinedBodies.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
combinedBodies.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
combinedBodies.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
combinedBodies.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
```

Please note that all the code in this question is basically my code, just that the new children are created through an iteration with different positions, rotations, and colors.

**EDIT WITH EXAMPLE CODE:** I have been able to recreate my issue in a test program which I have added here (the `allLine` is the parent of `ScreenLine` and `line` in this code).

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

enum type: UInt32 {
    case line = 1
    case screenLine = 2
    case allLine = 4
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let allLine = SKSpriteNode()
    addChild(allLine)
    var points = [CGPoint]()
    var bodies = [SKPhysicsBody]()

    points = [CGPoint(x: 0, y: 300), CGPoint(x: -200, y: 100)]
    let width = 5.0
    let height = {() -> Double in
        let distX = abs(points[1].x - points[0].x)
        let distY = abs(points[1].y - points[0].y)
        let dist = sqrt((distX * distX) + (distY * distY))
        return Double(dist)
    }()
    let ScreenLine = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.init(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0), size: CGSize(width: width, height: height))
    ScreenLine.position = CGPoint(x: ((points[1].x + points[0].x)/2), y: ((points[1].y + points[0].y)/2))
    let rotation = {() -> CGFloat in
        let m = (points[1].y - points[0].y)/(points[1].x - points[0].x)
        let angle = CGFloat(Double.pi/2) - atan(m)
        return -angle
    }()
    ScreenLine.zRotation = rotation
    ScreenLine.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: width, height: height), center: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    ScreenLine.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = type.screenLine.rawValue
    ScreenLine.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    ScreenLine.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
    ScreenLine.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    ScreenLine.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    allLine.addChild(ScreenLine)
    bodies.append(ScreenLine.physicsBody!)

    points = [CGPoint(x: -100, y: 300), CGPoint(x: -300, y: 100)]
    let line = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.init(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0), size: CGSize(width: width, height: height))
    line.position = CGPoint(x: ((points[1].x + points[0].x)/2), y: ((points[1].y + points[0].y)/2))
    line.zRotation = rotation
    line.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: width, height: height), center: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    line.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = type.screenLine.rawValue
    line.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    line.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
    line.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    line.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    allLine.addChild(line)
    bodies.append(line.physicsBody!)

    allLine.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: bodies)
    allLine.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    allLine.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = type.allLine.rawValue
    allLine.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    allLine.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
    allLine.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    allLine.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
}
}
```

**UPDATE:** Now by centering the physicsBody of the children to where the node is (not CGPoint.zero), but where I place the child on the screen, the physicsBody is in the right position when I add it to the list. 
I set the line and screen line physicsBody positions like this:

```
ScreenLine.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: width, height: height), center: ScreenLine.position)
line.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: width, height: height), center: line.position)
```

**PROBLEM THAT I'M CURRENTLY TRYING TO FIGURE OUT:**
This makes the physicsBodies of allLine centred. **However,** they aren't rotated like they should be. They don't preserve their rotations. How do I fix this??

Thanks for any answers and help :D

Comment: Every SKNode and its subclass has its own physics body. Why dont you try and see what will happen? Physics bodies of a children has nothing with a physics body of their parent.

Comment: What would be the best method for making the children's physicsBodies the parent's physicsBody?

Comment: There is an initializer, which initializes body(withBodies:)... So you would create parents body from its children bodies. Maybe you could try that. Or you can edit your question to clearly show what you are up to.

Comment: What I have there is basically my actual code, just that the children are at different positions, rotations, and colours. I was wandering if there was a way to 'group' all of the children's physicsBody so I can see if a node is in contact with that 'group' of physicsBodies.

Comment: Yeah, I think [bodyWithBodies:](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1519736-bodywithbodies) initializer might be of some help. It will group all bodies into one. I am not in front of a computer at the moment but you can try it by yourself

Comment: I have done SKPhysicsBody(bodies:) but that makes all the children disappear on the screen for some reason.

Comment: You mean sprites disappear? Check if parent is affected by gravity. Maybe it falls off the screen.

Comment: Yes, the children of the parent disappear (well I guess the parent does too but it is an empty sprite)

Comment: Do you see physics bodies? Set view.showsPhysics = true in your GameViewController to see physics visual representation. Also, update your question with a code which can reproduce what you are saying.

Comment: I can't see physicsbodies, but I just noticed that the nodes fall down at the bottom of the screen and soon fall of it. I think it's gravity, but I'm not in front of my computer now so I'll try later.

Comment: Now I have discovered that the physicsbodies of the parent aren't where the original physicsbodies of the children were, they are in the middle of the screen. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @Whirlwind I have added an example code that recreates my issue in my original post.

Comment: I will take a look at it closely tomorrow... You have to keep in mind, that when you add a child to a parent, it is positioned in parent's coordinate system. So, if you place the `allLine` node at 0.0, 0.0, it will be likely placed in the center of the screen (that is how it works by default when scene is loaded from .sks file). Same rules applies to both line nodes...Their parent is `allLine`, so you have to set their position relative to parent's coordinate system.

Comment: Thanks for that, now by centering the physicsBody of the children to where the node is (not CGPoint.zero), but where I place the child on the screen, the physicsBody is in the right position when I add it to the list. However, it doesn't preserve its rotation. How do I fix this??